# Using variables with parseInt in Java

Tags: java

So i'm supposed to collect data from user inputs for a game

```
int[] player1 = new int[4]; 
           try {
              player1[4] = Integer.parseInt(keyin.nextLine());
           }
           catch(NumberFormatException e) {
               System.out.println("Player 2 : ");  }
```

The try-catch is to skip to the next player when player1 presses Enter, but the problem I'm getting is I can't seem to find a way to use the variables the player1 has inputted. I need those values to compare with another, but using `int player1[0]` does not work.

Where can I find the values the person has entered?

An example of the program running:

```
Player 1: 12 1 5 // these numbers are user inputted
Player 2: 12 4 3
[...]
```

Comment: player1[4] will throw an IndexOutOfBoundsException.

Comment: @alterfox It does! Sometimes... I can't seem to make this work properly, any advice?

Comment: Yeah, read about arrays. This is basic stuff!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to setup a loop to both *read* in the inputs, as well as to *display* those inputs.

**Your code below does not work;** you are trying to access data that is beyond the bounds of your array.

```
player1[4] = Integer.parseInt(keyin.nextLine());
```

If you declare you array like this: `int[] player1 = new int[4];` 
Then you have the following indexes to use:

```
| 0 | 1 | 2 | 3 |` //This gives you 4 indexes! But player1[3] is the last usable index
```

Remember that when you are trying to access elements of arrays or any element in programming, computers begin numbering at **zero!** Any attempt to access data beyond this can result in undesired behavior, casuing the program to terminate abruptly.

I encourage you to examine the following resources:
http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/arrays.html

http://www.tutorialspoint.com/java/java_loop_control.htm

```
http://www.programmingsimplified.com/java/tutorial/java-while-loop

Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
System.out.println("Input an integer"); 

while ((n = input.nextInt()) != 0) {
  System.out.println("You entered " + n);
  System.out.println("Input an integer");
}

System.out.println("Out of loop");
```

}

Comment: So I changed it to  `for(int i=0;i<5;i++) {
        player1[i] = Integer.parseInt(keyin.nextLine());}
      }
      catch(NumberFormatException e) {
          System.out.println("Player 2 : ");  }`   But it still doesn't work for anything else but the first integer

Comment: @PatrickBui You still have a 1-over error. Your index doesn't go to 4. It only goes to 3. Please see the above example. If you try to access player1[4], this won't work. There is no valid data at that location. Your last accessible index is 3.

Please see updated example above

Comment: Sorry I forgot to write that i changed `int[] player1 = new int[4]` to `int[] player1 = new int[5]` !!

Comment: @PatrickBui  Try using the newly added snippet above, this should help

Answer (score 0):

```
String string = keyin.nextLine();
String[] parts = string.split("[ ]+");
```

Then check the size of parts and loop through that.